# Subquery returning more than one rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table REGULAR_TAB with following values-

```
VALUE_DEFN_ID        TYPE                     
-------------------------------------
15                   US_REGULAR_RATE            
16                   US_REGULAR_RATE           
18                   CA_FILING_STATUS
```

REGULAR_RANGE table

```
VALUE_DEFN_ID               VALUE
----------------------------------
15                           1.1
16                           1.2
18                           6
```

I have created a query where I use the below query as a subquery.Something like -

```
(select value
from REGULAR_TAB  TAB,
REGULAR_RANGE RANGE
WHERE TAB.VALUE_DEFN_ID = RANGE.VALUE_DEFN_ID
AND TAB.TYPE = 'US_REGULAR_RATE')
```

This is giving me two values and hence not working. Is there a way I can modify the subquery so that I can both 15 and 16 values in each. If I use ROWNUM = 1,it will randomly select the first row but I want it to be defined that always the 1st one i.e. 15 comes first and then 16 in the subquery order.....

Comment: What "above" query?  I am baffled on what you really want.  Sample data and desired results in a tabular format would help.  What is the query where the subquery is going?

Comment: @GordonLinoff- the query is too huge and hence cannot paste it.. the problem i have with this subquery as its creating multiple rows

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @SHSH_123 . . . Simplify to something that captures the essence of what you are asking.

Comment: Btw there is no ordering defined in a select without order by. To get all combinations of main select and your subquery you have to join them, e.g. select ... From mytab, (select ... From mytab) data without a join condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by **`ROWNUM`** in **`Oracle`** and **`LIMIT,OFFSET`** in **`MySQL`**.

**`Oracle`**

Here i had shared simple query for **`oracle`** by using,[**`OFFSET & ROWS`**](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results)

```
select value
        from REGULAR_TAB  TAB,
        REGULAR_RANGE RANGE
        WHERE TAB.VALUE_DEFN_ID = RANGE.VALUE_DEFN_ID
        AND TAB.TYPE = 'US_REGULAR_RATE' ORDER BY value OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Also for **`MySQL`**, i had shared query with
[**`Order by`** and **`Limit`**](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx#:%7E:text=LIMIT%20and%20ORDER%20BY%20clauses,rows%20the%20query%20will%20return.)clause.

**`MYSQL`**

```
select value
    from REGULAR_TAB  TAB,
    REGULAR_RANGE RANGE
    WHERE TAB.VALUE_DEFN_ID = RANGE.VALUE_DEFN_ID
    AND TAB.TYPE = 'US_REGULAR_RATE' order by value limit 1
```

This will help you.

Comment: and for the second row limit 2 ?

Comment: Nope, for second row you can try like `order by value limit 2,1`  ***Where 2 is offset and 1 means from there how many records you want***

Comment: There is no `limit` utility in Oracle

Comment: @JimMacaulay ***Mysql*** i am giving an idea, so he can similarly search for ***Oracle***

Comment: You can provide the idea as a comment, not as an answer

Comment: If your answer does not work using the product for which the question is tagged then your answer should be a comment on the question.

Comment: But still its justifiable, the question is on Oracle, but you have provided the solution in Mysql, which is incorrect

Comment: @JimMacaulay , I had updated my answer for Oracle as well. Also user had tag SQL in his question.

Comment: with the OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS, how will go to the next row ?

Comment: `OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS`